# Changing property value in nested records

Tags: c#, .net, c#-9.0

Is it possible to use the `with` keyword to create a new instance of nested records with a different value for the nested property - both cases: simple property and collection? Let's see an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var company = new Company(
            Name: "Company1",
            Branch: new Branch(
                Location: "Krakow",
                Employees: new[]
                {
                    new Employee("Robert")
                }));

        Console.WriteLine(company);
    }
}

internal record Company(string Name, Branch Branch);
internal record Branch(string Location, IEnumerable<Employee> Employees);
internal record Employee(string FirstName);
```

In the above example I want to create a new record, but with changed values of the branch location (`"Krakow"`) and employee name (`"Robert"`). How can I do this most effectively?

Comment: `var x = company with { Branch = company.Branch with { Location = "..." , Employees = company.Branch.Employees.Append("...").ToArray() }`. Use an `ImmutableList<T>` / `ImmutableArray<T>` instead of an `IEnumerable<T>` there to let you do `Employees = company.Branch.Employees.Add("...")`

Comment: You need to create a new instance of *all* records. You'll need `with` within `with`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can nest your `with` expressions:

```
var clone = company with {
    Name = "Company2",
    Branch = company.Branch with {
        Location = "Warshaw",
        Employees = new[]
        {
            company.Branch.Employees.First() with 
            {
                FirstName = "Bob"
            }
        }}};

Console.WriteLine(clone);
foreach (var e in clone.Branch.Employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LeviySoft.Visor](https://github.com/leviysoft/visor) to avoid awkwardness of nested withs:

```
[Optics(withNested: true)]
internal partial record Company(string Name, Branch Branch);
[Optics(withNested: true)]
internal partial record Branch(string Location, IEnumerable<Employee> Employees);
[Optics]
internal partial record Employee(string FirstName);

var original = new Company(...)

var updated = Company.FocusBranch.LocationLens.Set("Warshaw")(original)
```

As for the IEnumerable's - you can implement your own IProperty for the IEnumerables taking [this](https://github.com/leviysoft/visor/blob/main/src/LeviySoft.Visor.LanguageExt/Property.cs) as example. Please note that using non-immutable collection interfaces breaks by-value comparison of records (it's the reason why I did not implemented IProperty for IEnumerable)