# Non-destructive mutation of properties of nested record instances?

Tags: c#

In C#, I have a few nested `record` types. In total, these objects represent a JSON hierarchy and are used for deserialization of that data:

```cs
public record RadarrMetadata(
    IReadOnlyCollection<string> CustomFormats
);

public record SonarrMetadata(
    IReadOnlyCollection<string> ReleaseProfiles
);

public record JsonPaths(
    RadarrMetadata Radarr,
    SonarrMetadata Sonarr
);

public record RepoMetadata(
    JsonPaths JsonPaths
);
```

Is there a concise syntax for modifying the `CustomFormats` property? If so, please demonstrate an example of how I would use it. I tried a syntax like this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```cs
var data = new RepoMetadata(/*...*/);
var modifiedData = data with {
  JsonPaths.Radarr.CustomFormats = new[] {"newvalue"}
}
```

My goal is to avoid specifying properties I don't care about changing; such as `data.JsonPaths.Sonarr` while still getting a clean syntax.

Comment: I don't think this is possible using `with`. Instead, you could add a constructor that receives the original record plus your new CustomFormats.

Comment: I voted to close my own question. I found a similar question here with an answer I was satisfied with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448915/changing-property-value-in-nested-records

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap up your sub-properties to the top level to allow them to be modified by the `with` keyword:

```
    public record MyRecordA
    {
        public MyRecordB Sub { get; init; }
        public int Prop1
        {
            get => Sub.Prop1;
            init => Sub = Sub with{ Prop1 = value};
        }
    }
    public record MyRecordB
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; init; }
        public int Prop2 { get; init; }
    }
...
var r = new MyRecordA() { Sub = new MyRecordB() { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = 2 } };
var r2 = r with { Prop1 = 3 };
```

It does require a fair bit more code to setup, but that is the only workaround I know of. If used with a serializer, the wrapped properties should probably be marked to be ignored.